# Parse comma separated json using GSON

Tags: java, json, gson

I am not able to parse this JSON using GSON library IN JAVA

```
[{
"name": "ABC",
"sub": "maths"
}, {
"name": "DCF",
"sub": "SCI",
"class": 5
}]
```

Comment: What have you done so far, please show the code.

Comment: do you have a POJO of that schema?

Comment: No i am not having the POJO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use JsonParser

```
import com.google.gson.JsonArray;
import com.google.gson.JsonElement;
import com.google.gson.JsonParser;

...

String jsonStr = "[{\n" +
  "    \"name\": \"ABC\",\n" +
  "    \"sub\": \"maths\"\n" +
  "}, {\n" +
  "    \"name\": \"DCF\",\n" +
  "    \"sub\": \"SCI\"\n" +
  "}]";

JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
JsonElement jsonElement = parser.parse(jsonStr);
JsonArray json = jsonElement.getAsJsonArray();

json.get(0).getAsJsonObject().get("name").getAsString(); //will return abc
```

Comment: I dont think you can do that with gson, you might want to have a look at JsonPath https://github.com/jayway/JsonPath